# How do I find the address of a jump instruction?

Tags: architecture, mips, system, digital

I have a 26bit field in a jump instruction, which is `0x0100080`

If the top bit of the program counter are `0000`, the jump instruction refers to `0x00400200`.

Which address would jump instruction refer to if top four bits of `PC+4` are `1111`?

Comment: Look up `J` in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_